# In <link rel="icon">, is the sizes attribute required or optional?

Tags: favicon, rel, icon

I note that in the **WHAT-WG** section on:

```
link rel="icon"
```

Every `icon` referenced includes a `sizes` attribute:

```
<link rel=icon href=favicon.png sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel=icon href=windows.ico sizes="32x32 48x48" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
<link rel=icon href=mac.icns sizes="128x128 512x512 8192x8192 32768x32768">
<link rel=icon href=iphone.png sizes="57x57" type="image/png">
<link rel=icon href=gnome.svg sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml">
<link rel=stylesheet href=lsforums.css>
```

**Source:** https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/links.html#rel-icon

But, to my knowledge, the `sizes` attribute has never been **required**.

I'm trying to find an authoritative source confirming the `sizes` attribute is optional. I cannot.

In `<link rel="icon">`, is the `sizes` attribute required or optional?

I am specifically looking for an authoritative source - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for. I've added emphasis to the quote below:

> The sizes attribute gives the `sizes` of icons for visual media. Its
> value, ***if present***, is merely advisory. ***If specified***, the attribute
> [...] The attribute must only be specified on `link` elements that
> have a `rel` attribute that specifies the `icon` keyword or the
> `apple-touch-icon` keyword.
>
> **Source:** https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#attr-link-sizes

Comment: But if the `sizes` attribute _is_ present, is each size specified as _height_x_width_ or _width_x_height_? [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_sizes.asp) says the former, but what is the authority for this?

Comment: @WebSmithery check out [the HTML living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#rel-icon), it specifies that the first dimension is the width.